# Pass javascript variable to php in same file

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to pass a javascript variable to php code in the same file?

For example I did this, in my example.php:

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'example.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {var: 12345},
       success: function(data) {
             console.log("success");
       }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$var = $_POST['var'];
echo $var;
```

But it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: _“But it doesn't work”_ - well what would you _expect_ this to do if it worked? Even if your PHP script makes such an output, you don’t do anything with the received output on the client after your AJAX request. So what exactly did you expect to happen?

Comment: Perhaps you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming first of all, because the way you are asking makes me doubt a little bit whether you are aware of these basics yet.

Comment: Did you add jQuery librairie ?

Comment: Yes @executable.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: The question is really unclear but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645474/ajax-post-to-php-var-and-return/52645515#52645515) might be a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'example.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {var: 12345},
   success: function(data) {
         console.log("success");
   }
});
```

Your **AJAX** request expect a response (you assigned it to `data` variable).
You should elaborate more the value returned by your **PHP** script, like `console.log(data)` to see what it is returning.

Your **PHP** file can't write it directly to your html file, because it is a server-side operation and your page is already loaded. I think you should add some request-type logic in you PHP too if you want to have **HTML** file rendering and **Javascript AJAX** requests both in the same file.

A solution could be to catch the **AJAX[POST]** request in **PHP** code and return some **HTML** or **String** values to attach in HTML like `$(body).append(data);`

Here you can learn more: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp